# Ruby remove everything after first space

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.8.7

```
<%= @contact.foo_help %>
```

Outputs a number id and title (with a space between them), ex: 29292 This Is A Title.  I just want the number.  It won't always be the same amount of digits, and ocassionly I use numbers in my titles.

I was thinking the easiest way would be to gsub everything after the first space out, but I'm two weaks into this framework and can't get the synstax right! Please help

```
<%= @contact.foo_help.gsub( \s ' ')  %>
```

Comment: Are you using Rails, or just Ruby?

Comment: `gsub'`s arguments need to be separated by commas and the first argument has to be a string or a regular expression. If you want the latter, you have to use a regex literal (`/\s/`). I know you are new to the language, but that's basic stuff from ever howto or the documentation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
@contact.foo_help.gsub(/\s.+/, '')
```

Will match a space followed by one or more of any characters, and replace with an empty string.

Rubular is wonderful for this sort of thing http://rubular.com/

Answer (score 5):

I think the easiest/cleanest thing would be to use [`String#[]`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) with a regex argument:

```
<%= @contact.foo_help[/\d+/] %>
```

For example:

```
>> '29292 This Is A Title.'[/\d+/]
=> "29292"
>> '29292 This 9999 Is A Title.'[/\d+/]
=> "29292"
```

You could also tighten it up a bit and anchor the regex at the beginning of the string:

```
<%= @contact.foo_help[/\A\d+/] %>
```

but I don't know if you need the extra noise.

The basic idea is to say what you mean ("give me the number at the beginning of the string and I know it will begin with a number") rather than grabbing what you don't want and throwing it away.

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
str = "29292 This Is A Title"
number = str.to_i
=> 29292
number.class
=> Fixnum

'29292 555 This Is A Title 8989'.to_i
=> 29292
```

Hope this will help you.